# How to pass stdinput in a program running in background?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, youtube-dl

I have been trying to write a shell script which runs a command

```
youtube-dl -o C:\Users\3435\Desktop\35.mp4  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1rxfwFxB8M
```

This command can be exited by typing q on shell.

I can pass the parameter to script but how to do it automatically from within the script or through the other script.
I can kill this youtube-dl process from within the script but i dont want to do that as it effects the commad execution.

Kindly tell me how to make sure that q is being recieved by youtube-dl process either from another script or from within the same script.

Comment: That depends on whether `youtube-dl` is reading from the terminal directly, or from standard input. I don't know which is the case.

Comment: its reading from std input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect its standard input from a named pipe:

```
mkfifo ydl-input
youtube-dl -o 'C:\Users\3435\Desktop\35.mp4' \
           'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1rxfwFxB8M' \
           < ydl-input
```

then write "q" to the named pipe at any time later.

```
echo q > ydl-input
```

Comment: thanks @chepner it works for me .i had figured out this thing we need to create a pipe and then pass it to script.

Answer (score 0):

We may not need to do all of that. We are exporting the terminal printing output to a file and running the whole thing in the background.

```
youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/35.mp4  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1rxfwFxB8M > tmp.txt 2>&1 &
```

You may with to delete your outputs.